# Errors: Undeclared identifier 'DecimalSeparator' and no overloaded version of 'StringReplace'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Hi I have been coding and so far, there was no problem developing and compiling in Delphi 2007 in WinXP until Delphi XE7 in Win7.

I am not sure why it happened.

The line that the errors pointed to

```
....
if(tS<>'') then
begin
  Result:=StrToFloat(StringReplace(String(tS),'.',DecimalSeparator,[]));
  Invalid:=False;
end;
....
```

Errors:

```
1) [dcc32 Error] UtilNumString.pas(321): E2003 Undeclared identifier:     'DecimalSeparator'
2) [dcc32 Error] UtilNumString.pas(321): E2250 There is no overloaded version     of 'StringReplace' that can be called with these arguments
```

Please kin addvise. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old global variables for format settings have been removed.  You can either use the `FormatSettings` global variable :

```
Result:=StrToFloat(StringReplace(String(tS),'.',FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator,[]));
```

Or, alternatively (ideally...), you can create a local [`TFormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) and use that instead.

```
var
  fs : TFormatSettings;
begin
   fs := TFormatSettings.Create();
   Result:=StrToFloat(StringReplace(String(tS),'.',fs.DecimalSeparator,[]));
end;
```

Comment: I know that FormatSettings is not thread-safe, but is it actually deprecated?

Comment: FormatSettings hasn't been deprecated, they are just refactored to a record structure.